# Writing a COMPLETE pragma for a polymorphic pattern synonym?

Tags: haskell, ghc, pattern-synonyms

I have the following code and I don't know what should feed at `??`. Or cannot polymorphic patterns make complete?

```
{-# LANGUAGE PatternSynonyms #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ViewPatterns    #-}

module Data.Tuple.Single.Class
  ( Single (..)
  , pattern Single
  ) where

class Single t where
  wrap :: a -> t a
  unwrap :: t a -> a

pattern Single :: Single t => a -> t a
pattern Single a <- (unwrap -> a) where
  Single a = wrap a

{-# COMPLETE Single :: ?? #-}
```

[GHC document](https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/wikis/pattern-synonyms/complete-sigs) says that when all the conlikes are polymorphic you must type conlike.

When making `??` `()`, the compilation is successful. But what does `()` mean? And GHC says still non-exhaustive on usage.

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE PatternSynonyms #-}

{-# OPTIONS_GHC -Wno-orphans #-}

module Data.Tuple.Single.Only
  ( Single (..)
  , pattern Single
  ) where

import           Data.Tuple.Only         (Only (Only, fromOnly))
import           Data.Tuple.Single.Class (Single (unwrap, wrap), pattern Single)

instance Single Only where
  wrap = Only
  unwrap = fromOnly
```

```hs
ghci> Single a = wrap 1 :: Only Int

<interactive>:2:1: warning: [-Wincomplete-uni-patterns]
    Pattern match(es) are non-exhaustive
    In a pattern binding: Patterns not matched: _
```

- GHC 8.6.5

Comment: That wiki article suggests you can use `{-# COMPLETE Single :: () #-}`—have you tried that?

Comment: @JonPurdy I reflected your comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am no expert on `PatternSynonyms`, but from the looks of it, in case of polymorphic patterns we need to specify exact types that make them complete.

In the case of [`Only`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/Only-0.1/docs/Data-Tuple-Only.html) this would be:

```hs
{-# COMPLETE Single :: Only #-}
```

For the sake of example let's add another instance to `Single`:

```hs
instance Single Identity where
  wrap = Identity
  unwrap (Identity a) = a

pattern Single :: Single t => a -> t a
pattern Single a <- (unwrap -> a) where
  Single a = wrap a

{-# COMPLETE Single :: Only #-}
{-# COMPLETE Single :: Identity #-}
```

Which makes GHC to stop complaining:

```hs
λ> Single a = wrap 1 :: Identity Int
λ> Single a = wrap 1 :: Only Int
```

Comment: Addition: GHC says that Orphan COMPLETE pragmas not supported, a COMPLETE pragma must mention at least one data constructor or pattern synonym defined in the same module.